# Fill array with reverse and forward of own elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to fill an array with up to 'n' values using its existing 4 values. I want to fill it with a sort of pattern that goes reverse and forward until it reaches the capacity of 'n' values.

For example, with my array:

```
var array = [a, b, c, d];
```

I want the resulting array to follow this pattern:

```
array = [a, b, c, d,
         c, b, a, b, 
         c, d, c, b,
         a, b, c, d...(continues this pattern)]
```

Comment: Is it absolutely neccessary that this is an array? A function that returns the `i`th index of the resulting array is easier to implement and saves memory and time.

Comment: When should the pattern stop?

Comment: Hey Rick, the pattern shouldn't stop at a certain number since it depends on dynamic data. Optimally though it will be a number less than say 200? And it has to be an array since I am using the array as a part of a function with D3.js, and the contents of the array are actually colors that form a sort of color-pattern based on my data. What were you suggesting Nikola?

Answer (score 0):

**[concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)**, **[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**, and **[reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)** will get you going.

This repeats the pattern 100 times:

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for(var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
  array = array.concat(array.slice(0,3).reverse());
  array = array.concat(array.slice(1,4));
}

document.body.innerHTML= array.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

var step = 1;
var n = 10;
var length = array.length;
var result = [];

var i = 0, j = 0;
while(i !== n) {
  result.push(array[j]);
  j += step;
  if(j === 0 || j === (length - 1)) {
   step *= -1;
  }
  ++i;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d'];
var requiredLength = 20;

// first add the descending tail (thanks @RickHitchcock)
var sequence = array.concat(array.slice(0,array.length-1).reverse());

// now we can sample until done
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < requiredLength; ++i) {
   newArray.push(sequence[i % requiredLength]);
}
```

I suspect, however, that d3 can take a callback, in which case you just provide a function that generates the answer from the index.